# Define variable in Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline with bash code?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I would like to define a variable in Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml) in this spirit:

```
    variables:
      - TOP_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

But this doesn't work, I think because the value field must be an actual string. Any workaround? Should I just create a preliminary job that does `export TOP_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`?

Answer (score 0):

Export the variable at the top of your script.

```yaml
job-name:
  script:
    - export TOP_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
    - # npm run test # etc
```

GitLab has a number of useful [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) that you can reference in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.